# PMF conditioned on an Event

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

OK, so i cannot understand how to derive relationship between unconditional and conditional PMF, given an Event A, with P(A) > 0.

I know that $p_X(x) = P(A) \times p_{X|A}(x)$, but from definition of conditional probability, $p_{X|A}(x) = \frac{P(X=x\cap A)}{P(A)}$

Also by definition $p_X(x) = P(X=x)$. Combining these I get that $P(X=x) = {P(X=x\cap A)}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is not true that $p_X(x) = P(A)\times p_{X\mid A}(x)$.

Comment: It works on any examples that I have tried, and also I've seen this in a few youtube and online tutorials. However I would like to see explanation/derivation from a more reliable source.

Comment: If $p_X(x)=P(A)\times p_{X\mid A}(x)$ then $p_{X\mid A}(x) = p_X(x)/P(A)$. Since $p_{X\mid A}(x) = \mathbb P(\{X=x\}\cap A)/P(A)$, it follows that $$p_X(x) = \mathbb P(\{X=x\}\cap A), $$ which clearly is not true in general.